# If there is a certain value in one column use str_remove to the other column

Tags: r, if-statement, stringr

I have a dataframe with several columns which looks like this:

| State | Name |
| --- | --- |
| OS | OS state |
| CS | CS state |
| NYS | NYS state |
| TS | TS state |
| OS | state OS |

What I need to do is to delete state word if the state is equal to OS.
I do it in the following way:

```
if(State == "OS"){
Name <- str_replace_all(Name,"state","")
}
```

But it gives me an error: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. What am I doing wrong?

I am new to the if statements in R so I will be very grateful if somebody will help.

Comment: a simple suggestion you can do `dput(data_frame)` that helps for people to just copy it into R studio or any editor

Comment: if I understand you want to remove those rows which contain the string `OS`  is that it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` is used for scalars, use `ifelse` for vectorised operation.

```
df <- transform(df, Name = ifelse(State == "OS", 
                           sub('\\s*state\\s*', '', Name), Name))

df

#  State      Name
#1    OS        OS
#2    CS  CS state
#3   NYS NYS state
#4    TS  TS state
#5    OS        OS
```

If you are a `tidyverse` fan the same can be done using `dplyr` and `stringr` libraries.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- df %>% mutate(Name = if_else(State == "OS", 
                     str_remove(Name, '\\s*state\\s*'), Name))
```

`\\s*` in regex is to remove leading and lagging whitespace if any. `str_remove` is shorthand for `str_replace(string, pattern, "")`.